# Parsing values from string that represents sql query into dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following string, that represents SQL value:

```
msg = "INSERT INTO hires (id, hire_ts, user, hired_by) VALUES ('12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234'::uuid::UUID,  '2023-01-01T10:00:00.000000'::timestamp, 'doh', 'jason')"
```

I would like to parse two values from it: *user* and *hired_by*.
So far, I've been able to parse fields and values using the following pattern:

```
pattern = r"\(([^\)]+)\)"
re_msg = re.findall(pattern, msg)
```

This yields the following list:

```
re_msg    
['id, hire_ts, user, hired_by',
 "'12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234'::uuid::UUID,  '2023-01-01T10:00:00.000000'::timestamp, 'doh', 'jason'"]
```

How I do turn this into the following dict?

```
dict_msg = {
    "user": "doh",
    "hired_by": "jason"
}
```

Comment: You might find `split(', ')`  useful.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes for the example given but troublesome if hired_by == 'Jason,jones'

Comment: @DarkKnight OP isn't handling parentheses inside strings, so seems only fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```py
msg = "INSERT INTO hires (id, hire_ts, user, hired_by) VALUES ('12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234'::uuid::UUID,  '2023-01-01T10:00:00.000000'::timestamp, 'doh', 'jason')"

re_msg = re.findall(r"\(([^)]+)\)", msg)

re_msg = [ map(lambda x: x.strip().strip("'"), r.split(',') ) for r in re_msg]

dict_msg = { k:v for k,v in zip(*re_msg) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution (*maybe more accurate/safer*) would be to use [`sqlparse`](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse).

The main idea is to target the [Parenthesis](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/sqlparse/sql.py#L494) objects :

```
#pip install sqlparse
from sqlparse import parse
from sqlparse.sql import Function, Values, Parenthesis

def fn(p: Parenthesis):
    return map(lambda x: str(x).strip("'"), p.tokens[1].get_identifiers())

d = {
    fld:val for fld,val in zip(
        *[fn(j) for i in parse(msg)[0].tokens if isinstance(i, (Function, Values))
          for j in i.tokens if isinstance(j, Parenthesis)])
        # if fld in ["user", "hired_by"] # uncomment this line to pre-filter
}
```

Output :

```
print(d)

{'id': "12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234'::uuid::UUID",
 'hire_ts': "2023-01-01T10:00:00.000000'::timestamp",
 'user': 'doh',
 'hired_by': 'jason'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how you are storing this as a single list with two elements in it, you could break it into two separate lists and then zip them together, like this:

```
keys = re_msg[0].split(',')
values = re_msg[1].split(',')
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

you may need to do some cleaning on the values elements though to get what you need.